# Illegal use of ng-Transclude directive in the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compiler-construction, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

When I use `ngTransclude`, the page seems good,but got console error:

**Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: {0}**

I found the root cause: in index.js I used $compile to compile the modal directive.It seems $compile can't work with ng-transclude. Do you have some suggestion to fix this issue?

Here is the code

> directive.js:

```
myApp.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'modal/modal.html',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

        },
        controller: ['$scope', function transcludeController($scope) {

        }]
    }
});
```

> template.html:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"> ... </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> ... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> index.html:

```
<modal>
<input type="text" id="test"/>
</modal>
```

> index.js:

```
$scope.test = 'test';
$("#test").attr("ng-model", "test");
$compile(modal)($scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Plunker link. Its working there. if you can update the link with your code perhaps we can help you.

```
Link: https://plnkr.co/edit/ey1fXDwEOVtA64R6Io3q?p=preview
```